# C semantic meaning of multi line assignment

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I was browsing the linux kernel and there is something I don't fully understand. So while browsing [container_of.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/container_of.h) we find the following definition:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({              \
    void *__mptr = (void *)(ptr);                   \
    static_assert(__same_type(*(ptr), ((type *)0)->member) ||   \
              __same_type(*(ptr), void),            \
              "pointer type mismatch in container_of()");   \
    ((type *)(__mptr - offsetof(type, member))); })
```

I know exactly what the macro is doing because I used intrusive linked lists before, but normally the definition I use is a one liner something like:

```
#define container_of(__ptr__, __type__, __member__) ((__type__*)(__ptr__ - offsetof(__type__, __member__)))
```

What is escaping from my understanding is the semantic meaning of that multi line assignment, on a normal basis what you would do is something like

**type* *name* = container_of(*ptr*, type, member)** which would expand to

```
type* identifier = ({               
    void *__mptr = (void *)(ptr);                   
    static_assert(__same_type(*(ptr), ((type *)0)->member) ||   
              __same_type(*(ptr), void),            
              "pointer type mismatch in container_of()");
    ((type *)(__mptr - offsetof(type, member))); })
```

As a POC I wrote something easier

```
#define POC(__x__) ({assert(__x__ == __x__); 2;})

int __x__ = POC(0);                                                                                                       
printf("__x__: {%d}", __x__);                                                                                             

// 2 gets printed
```

Could someone please explain to me how this is able to compile and the semantic meaning of several statements for this just one and only assignment (I mean can I always assume the last value is the one used for the assignment or something like that)?

My understanding of brackets on C is that we can embed them to create new scopes wherever we want successfully emulating variable shadowing if we want so:

```
int main () {
    int x = 0;
    printf("x: {%d}", x); // Prints 0

    {
        int x = 1;
        printf("x: {%d}", x); // Prints 1
    }
}
```

But I never seen the above usage of a new scope for embedding context to the assignment

For whoever answers, thanks.

Comment: I believe that's using a [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs).

Comment: I think that's exactly what it is @Gene , thanks !!